# Submanifold from commutative algebra perspective

Tags: differential-geometry, commutative-algebra, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

It is well known that a Manifold is completely determined by its algebra of smooth functions. How can we describe a submanifold from an algebraic point of view?

Comment: If your first sentence means that a smooth manifold can be thought of as a locally ringed space (with the sheaf of smooth functions), then a submanifold can be thought of as a closed immersion of the locally ringed space. See for example, https://www.math.arizona.edu/~cais/CourseNotes/AlgGeom04/notes126.pdf